# How to set dynamic components in recyclerview item in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview page consists of question and answer fields .As per the question type I need to show the answer field from the json(e.g for "description" type edittext,"true/false" type then toggle button etc.What I tried is I have created all kind of answer field in the layout and made their VISIBILITY GONE,and as per json(answer type) I am making them VISIBLE .According to this approach if I have multiple edittext in the recyclerview item ,the values inserted are overlapping and on scroll values entered are getting cleared .So help me on how to set components and how to retrive the answers inserted .

MY recyclerview adapter class :

```
public class CheckSuiteFormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<AuditToday> formList;
    Context context;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    private boolean hasLoadButton = true;
    private final int TITLE = 0;
    private final int LOAD_MORE = 1;
    MyViewHolder headerHolder;
    CustomWatcher textWatcher;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView question_no, question ;
        public EditText answer;
        public Button btn_attach,btn_submit;
        public  CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4,cb5,cb6;
        public ToggleButton toggleButton;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            context = view.getContext();
            question_no = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_qs_no);
            question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_qs);
            answer = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_ans_text);

            btn_attach = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_attachment);
            frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.id_frame_layout);
            btn_submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

            //alignment settings for checkboxes start ------->
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params4.setMargins(60,100,0,0);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params5.setMargins(240,100,0,0);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params6 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params6.setMargins(400,100,0,0);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params1.setMargins(60,40,0,0);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params2.setMargins(240,40,0,0);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params3.setMargins(400,40,0,0);
            //alignment settings for checkboxes end ------->

            //alignment for toggle button
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params_toggle = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params_toggle.setMargins(60,100,0,0);


            cb1 = new CheckBox(context);
            cb1.setText("option1" );
            cb1.setLayoutParams(params1);
            frameLayout.addView(cb1);

            cb2 = new CheckBox(context);
            cb2.setText("option2" );
            cb2.setLayoutParams(params2);
            frameLayout.addView(cb2);

            cb3 = new CheckBox(context);
            cb3.setText("option3" );
            cb3.setLayoutParams(params3);
            frameLayout.addView(cb3);

            cb4 = new CheckBox(context);
            cb4.setText("option4" );
            cb4.setLayoutParams(params4);
            frameLayout.addView(cb4);

            cb5 = new CheckBox(context);
            cb5.setText("option5" );
            cb5.setLayoutParams(params5);
            frameLayout.addView(cb5);

            cb6 = new CheckBox(context);
            cb6.setText("option6" );
            cb6.setLayoutParams(params6);
            frameLayout.addView(cb6);

            toggleButton = new ToggleButton(context);
            toggleButton.setLayoutParams (params_toggle);
            frameLayout.addView(toggleButton);

            //visibility based on values
            answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //text_date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cb4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cb5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cb6.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
    public CheckSuiteFormAdapter(List<AuditToday> formList) {
        this.formList = formList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == TITLE) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.form_list_row, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }else if (viewType == LOAD_MORE) {
            return new FooterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checksuite_form_submit, parent, false));
        } else {
            return null;
            }
    }

    class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button btn;

        public FooterViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            this.btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById (R.id.btn_submit);
        }
    }

    HashMap<Integer,String> hsAllAns = new HashMap<>();
    public  class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private int position;

        public CustomWatcher(int position) {

            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//            int position = (int)editText.getTag(R.id.id_ans_text);
            Log.d("SUB", position+" "+s);
               hsAllAns.put(position,s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
            headerHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
            AuditToday auditToday = formList.get(position);
            headerHolder.question_no.setText(auditToday.getQuestion_no());
            headerHolder.question.setText(auditToday.getQuestion());
            String ans_type = auditToday.getAnswer();
            textWatcher = new CustomWatcher(position);
            if (ans_type.equals("desc")) {
                showDescriptionField();

            } else if (ans_type.equals("chk")) {
                showCheckBoxField();

            } else if (ans_type.equals("num")) {
                headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                headerHolder.cb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.answer.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                headerHolder.answer.setTag(position);
                headerHolder.answer.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            } else if(ans_type.equals("toggle")){
                headerHolder.toggleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                headerHolder.cb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.cb6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else if(holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            FooterViewHolder footer = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            footer.btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View view) {
                    Toast.makeText (context, "Clicked Header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    Log.d("Results :"," " +new Gson().toJson(hsAllAns) );

                }
            });
        }


    }
    public void showDescriptionField(){
        headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.answer.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        headerHolder.cb1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.cb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.cb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.cb4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.cb5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.cb6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.answer.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
    public void showCheckBoxField(){
        headerHolder.cb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.cb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.cb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.cb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.cb5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.cb6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headerHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        headerHolder.toggleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       // return formList.size();
        if (hasLoadButton) {
            return formList.size() +1;
        } else {
            return formList.size();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position >= formList.size()) {
            return LOAD_MORE;
        } else {
            return TITLE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code. Posting a broad question like this will not get answered.

Comment: I have added the code please suggest. If the question is not clear please let me know .

Comment: Can you also upload a image, its unclear what the problem is.